# How can i use WHERE condition in a wp_query?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use WHERE condition in a wp_query . I want to show posts that their ID is upper than 5 . How can i do this ?

Comment: This might help : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55687/compare-post-ids-within-wp-query-less-than-greater-than

Comment: @morteza jamali your question in still unclear, you should describe which post type should be, Custom post type or default post type or you talking about page

Comment: @Jignesh Bhavani don't suggest direct query filter, however this can be done by using `meta_query`

Comment: @Noman  Noted! :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this :

```
$exclude_ids = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__not_in' => $exclude_ids ) );
```

Comment: Your solution is not depend on the above question, please read again.

Comment: why ? I answered on question how get all posts with id upper then 5 ;)

Comment: The term `upper than 5` seems like greater than which is `>`, you should wait before posting solution until the question is clear.

Comment: By the way there is no posts with id < 1 in wordpress